# Install mahout on ubuntu 12.04 - E: Unable to locate package mahout

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, mahout, hadoop-plugins

How to I install mahout on ubuntu 12.04?

```
sudo apt-get install mahout
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mahout


https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Mahout+Installation
To install Mahout on an Ubuntu or other Debian system:
$ sudo apt-get install mahout
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Mahout installation manual](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Mahout+Installation) from Cloudera has the following section:

> **Mahout prerequisites**
>
> Important If you have not already done so, install Cloudera's yum,
> zypper/YaST or apt repository before using the instructions below
> to install Mahout. For instructions, see CDH3 Installation.

During the [CDH3 Installation](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/CDH3+Installation) Cloudera's package repository `http://archive.cloudera.com/debian <RELEASE>-cdh3 contrib` is being configured in your system, so that after following the manual you shall be able to install mahout using `apt-get`.

Comment: I am using chd4.  I see that mahout is here.  http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cdh/dists/precise-cdh4.1.2/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages.  So  given that....how do I add to apt?  Then do a apt-get update then apt-get install mahout.

Comment: If you're using cdh4, then you should follow [CDH4 Documentation](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/CDH4+Documentation). There is a special section for [Mahout installation](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Mahout+Installation). [CDH4 Installation](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/CDH4+Installation) has a step in which the apt repository is added. But judging from the lengthy documentation it won't be the only step. Maybe you could try the Cloudera demo Virtual Machine instead of installing CDH4 from stratch?

Answer (score 3):

It has never been distributed this way. Download from Apache or use Maven.

EDIT: ... never been distributed this way *by Apache*. If that's what you're looking for, download the tarball from Apache.

Comment: See my updated answer.  Should cloudera update there docs?  Hence my confusion or do I have to add a cloudera repo?

Comment: I don't know what this means -- CDH has Mahout in it but I don't think it's a separate package. If it is, it's Cloudera's own distribution only.

Comment: I am using cdh4.  Its a not officially supported app hence the agtp-get.  I am wondering if there is a apt repo I have to add.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-cache search mahout` shows that the package is not provide on the official Ubuntu repos.

You've to get it directly from [Apache](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/mahout/).